# hide the horizontal scrollbar is a bad idea?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have an html page with jquery slideshow (jquery circle plugin).
With the "shuffle" option

```
var slideshow = $('#slider').cycle({
 fx: 'shuffle', shuffle: { top: 0, left: 1300},
                ....
```

during the effect transitions moving images out off the page, displaying the horizontal scroll bar for a second, an annoying thing! If I just hide the horizontal scroll bar with CSS

```
html{
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

is a good idea? There are downsides to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page has a fixed width layout and your users are supposed to never use the horizontal scroll bar, it shouldn't be a problem at first look. However, if your page has 1000px+ width, and an user tries to access it with 800x600 resolution, they won't be able to scroll it so it may be a bad idea.

Not only that, your users may resize the window on purpose and they won't be able to use the scrollbar. You have to consider mobile users as well.

Comment: The layout is "flexible" from 1200 to 800 :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your page, but it shouldn't matter.